# Wordpress - Nothin Found Error after submiting a form

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a template page with a simple registration form. I wrote a php file to handle the form details and insert them in the database when the user clicks submit. Both files are located in the current theme's folder, but i receive an error saying "No results were found for your request". I know the problem is in the php file location. Where should i put it?

```js
<?php
global $wpdb
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lname'];

if(isset($first_name, $last_name))
{
 $wpdb->insert( 't_members', array( 'f_name' => $first_name, 's_name' => $last_name ));
}
?>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="process.php">
  <table id="registration">
    <tbody>
      <tr>  
        <th>    
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        </th>   
        <td>    
          <input type="text" id="fname" required> 
        </td>   
      </tr>                                                                                                         
      <tr>  
        <th>    
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        </th>   
        <td>    
          <input type="text" id="lname" required> 
        </td>   
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this code within some theme file or you're calling it directly?

Comment: the html is inside a theme file. it shows up fine on the site

Comment: And you want to submit to a standalone php file? Or a WP-driven page with different template applied to it?

Comment: Unless the process.php is a template and has a page associated to it, then the form's action url will be to that page. That's the only way the process.php can access WP's functions and etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) I sorted it